# How to find which combinations of my list of lists gives me the maximum average from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Dictionary `D` and a list of lists `D_best`. 
I want to find which combinations of my list gives me the maximum average from dictionary values.

```
D = {'Discount': {'D1': 15, 'D2': 26, 'D3': 19, 'D4': 14, 'D5': 20, 'D6': 42}}

D_best = [['D1', 'D6'], ['D3', 'D1']]
```

Combination1 = 57 `D1 + D6`

Combination2 = 34 `D1 + D3`

```
max(Combination1, Combination2)
```

retrun the best combination is `[D1, D6]`

**Constraints :**

1. I need to pick the best one from the D_best
2. D_best contains any number of elements in it, here in example shown are 2 i.e.,`len(D_best)`
3. length of each element within `D_best` would remain constant. For example `len(D_best[0])` will be same as `len(D_best[1])`

I have been trying this way:

```
D = {'Discount': {'D1': 15, 'D2': 26, 'D3': 19, 'D4': 14, 'D5': 20, 'D6': 42}}

D_best = [['D1', 'D6'], ['D3', 'D1']]

Dlist3 = []
for i in D_best:
    for j in i:
        Dlist3.append(j)
Dlist3 = set(Dlist3)  

disc_dict = {}
for i in Dlist3:
    disc_dict[i] = D['Discount'][i]

print(disc_dict)

c ={}
for n,i in enumerate(D_best):
    ck = ("c{}".format(n))
    c[ck] = i
print(c)

{'D3': 19, 'D1': 15, 'D6': 42}
{'c1': ['D3', 'D1'], 'c0': ['D1', 'D6']}
```

`

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't put code in comments. Give a [mcve] - *what happened* when you tried that way?

Comment: Explain what is not working in your code. Where in your code is your failure, how is it failing?

Comment: @idjaw  I am unable to pass the multiple list element to extract values from dictionary .

Comment: @ShravanKumar Edit your question to include this explanation. If you have any errors, show the traceback. The more you explain, the better.

Comment: @ShravanKumar, did you receive the answer you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of (combination, sum) for each combination in D_best:

```
l = [(comb, sum([D['Discount'][k] for k in comb])) for comb in D_best]
-> [(['D1', 'D6'], 57), (['D3', 'D1'], 34)]
```

Then take the best one by getting the maximum:

```
max(l, key=lambda (c,s): s)
-> (['D1', 'D6'], 57)
```

Or, to only get the combination and not the sum, take the first element instead:

```
max(l, key=lambda (c,s): s)[0]
-> ['D1', 'D6']
```

On a side note: In your Question you asked for the "maximum **average** from dictionary values", but in your example you just calculate the sum. This is only the same if your combinations are of equal length (all combinations of two values).

Comment: If you do it in a single step it's a dozen times more readable: `max(D_best, key=lambda l:sum(D['Discount'][i] for i in l))`

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. The one-liner is the champ. can you help me with this `max(l, key=lambda (c,s): s)`, it is throwing SyntaxError.

Comment: `max(l, key=lambda (c,s): s) ` help me with this line, not working for me. I'm using python3

Comment: Not sure how to do this in python3 and I cant test it right now. But you can just go with this: `max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])`, a little less pretty but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools`'s `combination` function, first we find out what is the best value

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter as at
k = 2.0
best_val =  max(sum(a)/k for a in combinations(D['Discount'].values(), k))
```

Then, get the indicies of the items:

```
best_ids = [ tuple(map(at(0), a)) for a in combinations(D['Discount'].items(), k) if sum(map(at(1), a)) == best_val*k]
```

**Note**: 
I did not understand whether only on couples or are triplets and larger tuples are also possible, you can iterate on `k` to support all possible sizes.

Comment: This compares all combinations of keys in the dict. He only wanted to find the best combination of the combinations listed in D_best. At least thats how I understand the question.

Comment: The question is not clear, OP did not specify the size of the combination, is 2 ? could it be any size ?

Comment: It does not need specification, since all the combinations he wants to look at are already in the list D_best. You should read the question again, this is not about finding all combinations.